# svcutil wsdl Error: The type name: on the property:"Name" of type:"System.CodeDom.CodeNamespace" is not a valid language-independent type name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, soap, soapui, svcutil.exe

When I use the Service Model Metadata Tool I get the following error

> svcutil wsdl Error: The type name: on the property:"Name" of
>   type:"System.CodeDom.CodeNamespace" is not a valid
>   language-independent type name.

when I execute the following line

```
svcutil my.wsdl /n:*,"www.abc.com/x" /out:my.cs
```

the namespace "/x" is the source of the error but I can't fix it.  I can change the namespace in the source document to "www.abc.com" and it works, no error, but that's not a solution as I don't own the source wsdl and can't change it to what I please.

Comment: Isn't the namespace setting supposed to be something like `/n:http://www.example.com/x,MyNamespace.X`?

Comment: yes, that's correct, csv of namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [DavidG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663001/davidg) `www.abc.com/x` is not a valid namespace

[ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe)

> Specifies a mapping from a WSDL or XML Schema targetNamespace **to a CLR
>   namespace**. Using '*' for the targetNamespace maps all targetNamespaces
>   without an explicit mapping to that CLR namespace.
>
> To make sure that the message contract name does not collide with
>   operation name, you should either qualify the type reference with ::,
>   or make sure the names are unique.
>
> Default: Derived from the target namespace of the schema document for
>   Data Contracts. The default namespace is used for all other generated
>   types.
>
> Short Form: /n Note: When generating types to use with XmlSerializer,
>   only a single namespace mapping is supported. All generated types will
>   either be in the default namespace or the namespace specified by '*'.

Comment: svcutil Import.wsdl /n:*,"import.www.abc.com" /out:Import.cs
This was what finally worked.  I didn't realize the second /n param was the destination namespace, I thought it was the wsdl of origin namespace.